# How do you return ObjectResult instances from an exception handler?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

In a controller action I can return an object that gets serialized.  I use the OK() and BadRequest() functions as follows because they make it so clean:

```
[HttpPost()]
[SwaggerResponse(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest, "Request is not multi-part content.", typeof(MyErrorObject))]
public async Task<ActionResult<Myobject>> Post()
{          
    try
    {
        return Ok(new MyObject());
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return BadRequest(new MyErrorObject(ex));
    }
}
```

I want to change my error handling by setting up a global handler as follows:

```
public class Startup
{

   ...

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        ...

        app.UseExceptionHandler(errorApp =>
        {
            errorApp.Run(async context =>
            {
                ...
            });
        });
        ...
    }
}
```

What I want to know is, how can I use the ObjectResult classes like BadRequestResult, OKResult etc, from within an exception hander like in the above pattern?

Comment: Hi @Jeremy,I have doubt that the ExceptionHandler is used to deal with the 500 internal error,only if you throw exception then it would get into such middleware.No matter 200 or 400 error,they would not get into the middleware.

Comment: It appears that any exception thrown will get into the middlewhere, which is what I want.  In my controller actions I will handle success because the response is different for each action.  In the exception handler middlewhere I want to handle exceptions because the response format is always the same.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to know how to return ObjectResult in middleware,you could follow:

Startup.cs:

```
app.UseExceptionHandler(errorApp =>
{
    errorApp.Run(async context =>
    { 
        context.Response.StatusCode = 400;
        var error = context.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>();
        var response = new BadRequestObjectResult(new MyErrorObject(error.Error.Message));

        var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(response);
        await context.Response.WriteAsync(json);
    });
});
```

Model:

```
public class MyErrorObject
{
    public MyErrorObject(string msg)
    {
        ErrorMessage = msg;
    }
    public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Get()
{
    ModelState.AddModelError("id", "notunique");
    throw new Exception(ModelState.Values.First().Errors.First().ErrorMessage);
}
```

Result:
[image]

**Update:**

The middleware seems cannot return model by default.You could custom HttpContext extension to make it available:

HttpContextExtension:

```
public static class HttpContextExtensions
{
    private static readonly Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.RouteData EmptyRouteData = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.RouteData();

    private static readonly ActionDescriptor EmptyActionDescriptor = new ActionDescriptor();

    public static Task WriteModelAsync<TModel>(this HttpContext context, TModel model)
    {
        var result = new ObjectResult(model)
        {
            DeclaredType = typeof(TModel)
        };

        return context.ExecuteResultAsync(result);
    }

    public static Task ExecuteResultAsync<TResult>(this HttpContext context, TResult result)
        where TResult : IActionResult
    {
        if (context == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));
        if (result == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(result));

        var executor = context.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IActionResultExecutor<TResult>>();

        var routeData = context.GetRouteData() ?? EmptyRouteData;
        var actionContext = new ActionContext(context, routeData, EmptyActionDescriptor);

        return executor.ExecuteAsync(actionContext, result);
    }
}
```

Middleware for BadRequest:

```
app.UseExceptionHandler(errorApp =>
{
    errorApp.Use((context, next) =>
    { 
        context.Response.StatusCode = 400;
        var error = context.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>();
        var response =new BadRequestObjectResult(new MyErrorObject(error.Error.Message));
                
        return context.WriteModelAsync(response);
        //return Executor.ExecuteAsync(actionContext, result);
    });
});
```

Middleware for OKResult:

```
app.UseExceptionHandler(errorApp =>
{
    errorApp.Use((context, next) =>
    { 
        context.Response.StatusCode = 200;
        var response = new OkObjectResult("success");
        //var response = new OkResult();
        return context.WriteModelAsync(response);
    });
});
```

Comment: It's true you could do the serialization yourself, but, the nice thing about returning ObjectResults from a controller action is that the correct formatter will handle serialization/deserialization for you based on formatters that have been set up, where as explicit serialization code from the exception handler does not.

Comment: The middleware seems cannot return model by default.You could custom HttpContext extension to make it available.Please check my answer.